How to match csv items? (round 2)
As Vivian answered in , using
\v(^|,)\zs([^,"]*|("[^"]*")|(""".{-}"""))\ze(,|$)

can match csv items such as:

simple e.g.: ,abc,, whose content is just abc
with quotation mark, e.g.: ,"abc,abc", whose content is abc,abc
with quotation mark, within which there are double quotation mark that is an escape of a single quotation mark, e.g.: ,"""abc""", is an item that the content is "abc" , and """abc,abc""" means "abc,abc"

But there are more tricky ones, namely the double quotation marks escape is not at the beginning, for example, ,"abc""def""gh", is actually a cell with the content abc"def"gh. Is there a way to match this with vim regex?

This is really where Miller starts to shine… it should handle this case flawlessly

To match "abc""def""gh" I would propose:
\v(^|,)\zs(([^,"]+)|("([^"]*"")*[^"]*"))\ze(,|$)

Or:
\v%(^|,)\zs(%([^,"]+)|%("%([^"]*"")*[^"]*"))\ze%(,|$)

Where:

("([^"]*"")*[^"]*") match item of the like "foo""bar""foo

Remark: In order to manage csv file you could be interested to the following plugins:

csv.vim or
rainbow_csv


it seems \zs and \ze have to be a matched item, ie. could not be ignored as %(...) , is that so?

You can use not catching group %() if you like. I have proposed an alternative version that only catch the value.

sorry i wasn't clear, i mean the \ze itself seems is always captured, as an empty string.

Indeed that is the behavior of \zs and \ze. Is this something you want to change ?

ah thanks confirming it. nothing wrong about it. just there's only \1 to \9, so in some complex matching, I tried to use %(\ze) but not working, so i'll not use \ze but use \=printf("%s...", SomeTransformFunction(submatch(1))...).

ah, i found it. \v(("([^"]|"")*")|([^,"]*))
